# jquery curvycorners effect without changing size of an element

Tags: jquery, rounded-corners

is there a way to make the curvycorner effect but have no padding inside the div? when i apply the corners it makes the div its applied to bigger vertically and horizontally to implement the corners.

this is the plugin for jquery im talking about:

http://code.google.com/p/jquerycurvycorners/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the generated source code and modify the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [jQuery Corner plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/) instead. I've tried almost all of available jQuery corner plugins and most of them didn't satisfy me. Either the width/height got messed up as you encountered, or transparency didn't work well, or the floats got mad, or there were browser inconstenties, or they shipped with gifs, or the documentation/support was poor. The linked one did its job right.